# pip freeze takes 26 seconds as root and 1.6 as user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, python, pip

Why takes pip freeze as superuser that long (roundabout 26s) and just a second and a bit more (roundabout 1.5s ) for normal users ? And how could i get deeper into the reasons ?

Comment: have you tried `--verbose` ?

Comment: sure but i used -vvv, no extra output except the tempdir path

Comment: sudo python -v -m pip freeze 
shows a long waiting between these both lines

    import keyrings.alt.file # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keyrings/alt/file.pyc
    import Crypto # directory /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto

which module ist that ? pycrypt ? I'm on 2.6.1 so its the latest....